# Comparator case insensitive string set

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, set, comparator

I was just checking effective STL(book) example for set comparator to implement case insensitive set, but i am facing problems(visual studio says comaparator not valid but it worked in ideone). I am sure there is something wrong in my implementation even then it is little confusing what is right.

Below is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
    inline int ciCharCompare(char c1, char c2) // case-insensitively compare chars
    { // c1 and c2, returning -1 if c1 < c2,
      //0 if c1==c2, and 1 if c1 > c2
        int Ic1 = tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c1)); //see below for
        int Ic2 = tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c2)); // info on these
        if (Ic1 < Ic2) return -1;
        if (Ic1 > Ic2) return 1;
        return 0;
    }

struct CiStringCompare : public std::binary_function<string, string, bool>
{

    int ciStringCompareImpl(const string& s1, const string& s2) const
    {
        auto p = mismatch( //see below for an
            s1.begin(), s1.end(), //explanation of why
            s2.begin(), //we need not2;see
            not2(ptr_fun(ciCharCompare))); //Item 41 for why we
                                           // need ptr_fun
        if (p.first == s1.end()) { //if true, either s1 and
            if (p.second == s2.end()) return 0; // s2 are equal or
            else return -1; //s1 is shorter than s2
        }
        return ciCharCompare(*p.first, *p.second);
    }
    int xxxx(const string& s1, const string& s2) const
    {
        if (s1.size() <= s2.size()) return ciStringCompareImpl(s1, s2);
        else return -ciStringCompareImpl(s2, s1);
    }

    int operator()(const string& str1, const string& str2) const {
        return xxxx(str1, str2);
    }
};

class DifferenceBetweenEquivalenceandEquality
{
    // Comparator functor 


    set<string, CiStringCompare> s;
public:
    DifferenceBetweenEquivalenceandEquality(const vector<string>& v)
    {
        for (const auto& x : v)
            s.insert(x);
    }

    void print() {
        for(const auto& x: s)
            cout << x << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    DifferenceBetweenEquivalenceandEquality dbee({ "STL","stl","aaa","bbb" });
    dbee.print();
    return 0;
}
```

It is working fine in ideone though, so im confused as to what makes a comparator valid and how the equality, equivalence and ordering effect by each of these
For example :: In normal set i get

> `STL stl aaa bbb`

but using the below comparator i get

> `aaa bbb stl STL`

```
inline string toLowerCase(const string& str) {
    string res(str);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < (int)res.size(); i++)
        res[i] = (char)tolower(res[i]);

    return res;
}

class NormalComparator
{
public:
    bool operator()(const string& s1, const string& s2)
    {
        return toLowerCase(s1) < toLowerCase(s2) ||
            !(toLowerCase(s2) < toLowerCase(s1)) && s1 < s2;
    }
};
```

Comment: The comparator's `operator()` must return a boolean - `true` if the first argument should precede the second in the desired order, `false` otherwise. It is not, I repeat not, a tri-state "negative for less-than, positive for greater-than, zero for equals". Since your comparator doesn't satisfy the requirements, your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: hi, i tried that too. It makes no difference. The thing i find strange is the equality and equivalence relationship of comparator. visual studio is not accepting the comparator for the same reason i believe. While other compiler is. I tried few other comparators too... i cannot understand the equality and precedence in VS. May be it is not properly done in VS or strictly done.

Comment: Show the code where you "tried that too". You must have done something wrong. I can assure you that `std::set` with a correctly written custom comparator works just fine in MSVC.

Comment: The only reason i didn't use bool is because i thought it would the int value returned from the comparator to order the values accordingly. bool is just for equality what about ordering?!

Comment: Which part of "return `true` if the first argument should precede the second in the desired order, `false` otherwise" do you find unclear?

Comment: Just returning false in case of mismatch above instead of -1 and 1 should do right? am i wrong? can you please give me a small code example.

Comment: In `operator()`, make it `return xxxx(str1, str2) < 0;`

Comment: I do not want to bother you more. I am slowly getting your point, may be i need to look a little deeper though. Extremely grateful for your time. Thank you